# How can I know the classes of a given package

Tags: java, class, size, package

Given a package in java language, I want to know how many classes it contains and their list (list of these classes).

I can access to my package with `myClass1.class.getPackage()` but after this I **don't** have some thing like `getClasses()` or `size()` or `lenght` or `ClassesCount()`.

Thank You

Comment: You'll have to write your own classloader for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library which might allow to achieve this easily:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = 
           reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
```

I guess you can use `Object` in place of `SomeType` as Object is the super class of all the class in java:

```
 Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = 
     reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, classes are loaded dynamically. So there's simply no way to do what you're trying to do; the virtual machine itself does not know the full list of classes within a package.

Comment: but when I am programming and I write  `myPackage.` just after writing point(.) I have the list of all classes but not when I write  `myClass.class,getPackage()`

Comment: Right. Your development environment knows what all the classes are; it has to, because it needs to compile them. But this information is not available to the program itself unless you explicitly put it in.

Answer (score 1):

There are already many questions and answers on this,
you can follow these links

a) [How to get all classes names in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519626/how-to-get-all-classes-names-in-a-package)

b) [How can I list all classes loaded in a specific class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681459/how-can-i-list-all-classes-loaded-in-a-specific-class-loader)

c) [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: I am sorry, I saw the first one  and the second one they are not exactly like mine, but the last one is. what to do? should I delete the question?

Comment: @RiadSaadi I think you should not delete there are already many useful expert comments in this post.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi As you know that this is a duplicate of other questions so you should not post as answer.

Comment: but in the reglementation, what to do in duplicate case?

Comment: @RiadSaadi, please, if you think that your question is a duplicate, go ahead and remove it. I am an answerer too, but I should not answer a question which has already complete answer somewhere else and better than mine.

Comment: @rocking, yes you are right, will take care of this.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi There is a possibility of getting downvotes if you answer duplicate questions.So i just made you aware of it