# Getting all classes in a package, and turning them into a FooBar variable

Tags: class, arraylist

I have a lot of classes in a package that all extend `FooBar`, and I wish to make an `ArrayList<FooBar>` variable.

So far, I have just been adding them one by one into the `ArrayList` on startup and I hate it, because I often forget to add it to the list.

Comment: 1. Which language? 2. Where's your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all classes names in a package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519626/how-to-get-all-classes-names-in-a-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Java to me. Getting all classes in a package is tricky, as you have to use the Java Reflection API. You could do this using Reflections (http://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

 Set<Class<? extends FooBar>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(FooBar.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, however, the part I am having troubles with is getting the ArrayList<FooBar>

Comment: Do you mean ArrayList<FooBar> or ArrayList<Class<? extends FooBar>>? Still not sure what exactly you are planning to do.

Comment: All the classes in the package extend FooBar, and I have been adding them to the arraylist 1 by 1 as in

    `foobarArrayList.add(new SomeRandomClassThatExtendsFooBar());`

but I want it to automatically add them to the ArrayList<FooBar>..

Comment: Okay, using the above code (and assuming that each of the classes provde a default constructor) it would be something like `for (final Class<? extends FooBar> clazz : subTypes) {foobarArrayList.add(clazz.newInstance();}`. Keep in mind that this can already be considered as an ugly hack. It is not good coding style...